# Trying to Get SELECT TOP to work with Parameter in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is building on some code I got the other day (thanks to peterm). I am now trying to select the TOP X number of results after calculations on the query. The X can range from 1 to 8 depending on the number of results per player.

This is the code I have but I get a syntax error when I try to run it.

```
SELECT
  PlayerID
, RoundID
, PlayedTo
, (SELECT Count(PlayerID) FROM PlayedToCalcs) AS C
, iif(
    C <= 6
  , 1
  , iif(
      C <= 8
    , 2
    , (
        iif(
          C <= 10
        , 3
        , (
            iif(
              C <= 12
            , 4
            , (
                iif(
                  C <= 14
                , 5
                , (
                    iif(
                      C <= 16
                    , 6
                    , (
                        iif(
                          C <= 18
                        , 7
                        , (iif(C <= 20, 8, 999))
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ) AS X
FROM PlayedToCalcs AS s
WHERE PlayedTo IN (
  SELECT TOP (X) PlayedTo
  FROM PlayedToCalcs
  WHERE PlayerID = s.PlayerID
  ORDER BY PlayedTo DESC, RoundID DESC
)
ORDER BY PlayerID, PlayedTo DESC, RoundID DESC;
```

Here is a link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a726c/4 with a small sample of the data I'm trying to use it on.

Comment: The database i'm working on is in Access 2013

Comment: What happens when you remove (x) and replace it with desired number as in SELECT TOP 10 ...? or SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT ...?

Comment: Personally, whenever I need something more than one or two values translated, I specify a table (either as a temp, or via a CTE).  This _greatly_ simplifies the query, especially when you otherwise have to nest parenthesis...

Comment: May I suggest using the `switch` function instead of `iif` to handle multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks Yawar for the suggestion it looks like it may be a better solution but I seem to be getting a syntax error when I try it. Here is the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a726c/41

Comment: Your SQLFiddle example uses SQL Server, which doesn't have the `switch` function--the `switch` function is available in Access only.

Comment: I have changed the switch statement to a case statement but there is still a syntax error.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a726c/50

Comment: The syntax error you're seeing in SQL Fiddle is because in SQL Server (T-SQL), you can't use a column alias you've just defined in the same `select` statement. E.g., you can't do `select 1 as a, a * 2 as b from some_table`. You _can_ do it in Access SQL though, which is why the query should work in Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Access db engine does not allow you to use a parameter for `SELECT TOP`.  You must include a literal value in the SQL statement.

For example this query works correctly.

```sql
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM tblFoo
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

But attempting to substitute a parameter, *how_many*, triggers error 3141, *"The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."*

```sql
SELECT TOP how_many *
FROM tblFoo
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason being in SQL Server (the simulator you used in SQL Fiddle), you cannot use `IIF`. Try using `CASE`.

And there is a limitation of using 7 nested `IIF` in Access.

Comment: Actually, `IIF()` _does_ work in SQL Server 2012, so you may want to specify that.

Comment: How would the code need to be changed to get it to work in 2012. You only need to change a setting up in the top left to change from 2008 to 2012.