# Why is Access asking for a param arg here?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

In order to test whether a particular query against an MS Access "database" *should* be returning any records (it's not), I am running it in Access like so:

```
SELECT TOP 5 t_accounts.account_no as AccountID, IIF(ISNULL(t_accounts.name),'[blank]',t_accounts.name) AS Name 
FROM t_accounts 
INNER JOIN td_department_accounts ON (t_accounts.account_no = td_department_accounts.account_no) 
WHERE (AccountID >= 1) AND type = 'DE'
```

The "*Top 5*" and the "*AccountID >= 1*" are hardcoded versions of what I'm using in the code:

```
cmd.CommandText = 
        string.Format(
        @"SELECT TOP {0} t_accounts.account_no as AccountID, IIF(ISNULL(t_accounts.name),'[blank]',t_accounts.name) AS Name 
        FROM t_accounts 
        INNER JOIN td_department_accounts ON (t_accounts.account_no = td_department_accounts.account_no) 
        WHERE (AccountID >= @firstId) AND type = 'DE'", CountToFetch);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstId", FirstId);
```

Yet Access prompts me with:

[image]

(If I enter "1", it does then return a few records).

What must I do to get Access' query running process to straighten up and fly right? Or is it me that has vertigo?

### UPDATE

Perhaps a clue is that with the C# code shown above, I get, "*No value given for one or more required parameters.*" Why? The only parameter is firstId, and it's value is indeed supplied...?!?

### UPDATE 2

Even though it works, running Code Analysis on it causes that august tool to wrinkle its brow, scowl, and growl:

```
CA2100  Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities The query
string passed to 'OleDbCommand.CommandText.set(string)' in
'NRBQSQLRepository.GetNDepartmentsFromID(string, int)' could contain
the following variables 'CountToFetch'. If any of these variables
could come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a
parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string
concatenations.
```

Comment: perhaps t_accounts is a view requiring a parameter. I think access supports such things: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx

Comment: No, t_accounts is a table.

Comment: I could have sworn that `?` was the place holder for parameters in access.

Comment: @ConradFrix: Maybe so, but there's nary a "?" in the bunch. In fact, none at all. So why is Access thinking there's a param in my query? *What* in there does it think is a param?

Comment: In any case the WHERE clause should be   `WHERE (t_accounts.account_no>= 1) AND type = 'DE' ` you can't reference an alias in a where clause... sorry

Comment: @ConradFrix: That was the problem. Well, it led to "data type mismatch" and when I changed "1" to "'1'" (IOW, I encased it in single quotes), it now works. If you make this an answer (cannot reference an alias in a where clause) I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @ConradFrix you can use any string as a parameter in an access query. Now if you are coming at access through ADO or you are creating ad hoc queries with parameters it's another story..

Comment: [You can't parameterize top](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20867352/119477) I would make sure `CountToFetch` is an integral value and surpess the warning in Code Analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Why does Access want me to enter a parameter value?](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-HA010274377.aspx)

> Access displays the Enter Parameter Value dialog box when you open an
>   object that contains an identifier or expression that Access cannot
>   interpret.

In this case `AccountID` is the field alias for `t_accounts.account_no`. You tried to reference the field alias in the Where clause. You can't do that.

change

`WHERE (AccountID >= 1) AND type = 'DE'`

to

`WHERE (t_accounts.account_no>= 1) AND type = 'DE'`